# Xamarin Forms Button IsVisible Binding not Working on Android

Tags: android, binding, xamarin.forms, converters

I tried searching for the same error with no results so here's my question:

I have a Xamarin form project that will be deployed on Android and iOS. In one of my views i have 2 buttons that will only be visible if the user has selected a few option first. This is working just fine on iOS, but when I deploy on the Android simulator the buttons are not being displayed unless I switch orientations. Here's a sample of the code:

```
<Button
    Grid.Column="0"
    Grid.Row="0"
    TextColor="{StaticResource AwesomeTxtColor}"
    Text="Click Me"
    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AwesomeBgColor}"
    IsVisible="{Binding SelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource isGreaterOrEqualZero}}"
    Command="{Binding AwesomeCommand}" />
```

Again, converter is working per debugging session and bindings too. The issue is only happening for me on Android. iOS is working as expected. Xamarin Forms version: 2.3.4.267. Anyone have experienced this before or have any ideas on what might be the problem?

Comment: It may be an layout issue. When the view doesn't fit in the container, android omits that view. This Grid (wich is the button container) have width and height definitions setted as `Auto`?

Comment: Hm that make sense. I will get back to you on the height. I believe it is Auto. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Okay. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Alright so it was set to "*", i changed it to 75 just for testing still same results. Buttons are not being displayed unless i switch orientations :/

Comment: Same behavior with "Auto". Buttons did not appear.

Comment: I appreciate your help. It makes perfect sense to me what you said. Could the columns width be an issue too? Should i use "Auto" too?

Comment: Just tested it... same issue :(

Comment: Yes. You do. If you can share the whole page code maybe someone else can take a look too.

Comment: Code is too big and since it's for a client i would have to change a lot  to make it S.O. friendly :(

Comment: I got it. What if you try change the layout of the button's container to a StackLayout? Just to make a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157826/discussion-between-ph0b0x-and-diego-rafael-souza).

Comment: I've changed the layout which is something like: StackLayout > Grid > Buttons.... still same problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it was a threading issue. Lists used to populate pickers on my view were loaded using:

```
await Task.Run(() => {
  //API calls to load lists
});
```

I changed that to:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
  //API calls to load lists
});
```

And now Android updates the UI. Odd but apparently those values on the lists were stuck on a different thread...